# Item in ScrollView is not seen in Scene, but it shows in hierarchy

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I am trying to display a list, generated dinamically. I created a prefab with the things I need in it (a TextView, 3 TMP_InputFields and 2 Buttons.)

To manage the different list items, I created a script (SkillManager, since the items represents skill the player can choose), which I attached to the prefab.[image]

Then, I add every item (currently I am adding only one for testing purposes) to a List, iterate that list, and add the prefab to the Content of a ScrollView:

```
for(int i = 0; i < listaSkills.Count; i++)
    {
        GameObject listItem = Instantiate(SkillPrefab) as GameObject;
        listItem.GetComponent<SkillManager>().skill = listaSkills[i];
        //listItem.transform.SetParent(SkillsContent.transform, false);
        listItem.transform.parent = SkillsContent.transform;
    }
```

When I run this, no item is seen in the ScrollView, but I can see the SkillItem added to the hierarchy:

[image]

If I move to Scene tab after playing, I see a square with red lines crossing it:

[image]

Why is my item not displaying? Why the red cross? How can I populate my ScrollView?

EDIT:

This is the code of SkillManager, the script added to SkillPrefab:

```
public class SkillManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public TMP_InputField toSpend;
public TMP_InputField rangos;
public TMP_InputField modificadores;
public TMP_InputField total;
public Button plusButton;
public Button minusButton;
public TMP_Text nombre;
public Skill skill;
private int modificador;
private int pointsToSpend;
private int totalPoints;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    print("Start");
    if(total!=null)
    total.text = "0";
    if(modificadores!=null)
    modificadores.text = "0";
    if (toSpend != null)
    {
        toSpend.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text = GetSkillPoints();
        totalPoints = int.Parse(total.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text);
        pointsToSpend = int.Parse(toSpend.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text);
    }
    else
    {
        GameObject GameObjectToSpend = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("tospend");
        toSpend = GameObjectToSpend.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>();
        if (toSpend == null)
        {
            print("Sigue siendo nulo");
        }
        else
        {
            toSpend.text= GetSkillPoints();

            //totalPoints = int.Parse(total.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text);
            if(total!=null)
            totalPoints = int.Parse(total.text);
            if(toSpend!=null)
            pointsToSpend = int.Parse(toSpend.text);
        }
    }
    if (skill != null)
    {
        modificador = GetModificador(skill);
        string sModificador = modificadores.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text;
        int iModificador = int.Parse(sModificador);
        modificadores.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text = iModificador.ToString();
    }

    if (plusButton != null)
    {
        plusButton.onClick.AddListener(PlusButtonClicked);
        minusButton.onClick.AddListener(MinusButtonClicked);
    }
    
}

private string GetSkillPoints()
{
    return "1";
}

public void MinusButtonClicked()
{
    string ranks = rangos.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text;
    int ranksInt = int.Parse(ranks);
    if (ranksInt > 0)
    {
        int newRank = ranksInt - 1;
        pointsToSpend += 1;
        rangos.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text = newRank.ToString();
        toSpend.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text = pointsToSpend.ToString();
        total.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text = (newRank + modificador).ToString();
        skill.Puntos = newRank;
    }
}

public void PlusButtonClicked()
{
    
    string ranks=rangos.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text;
    int ranksInt = int.Parse(ranks);
    Character character = Almacen.instance.Character;
    int level = character.CharacterLevel;
    if (ranksInt < level && pointsToSpend > 0)
    {
        int newRank = ranksInt + 1;
        rangos.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text = newRank.ToString();
        pointsToSpend -= 1;
        toSpend.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text = pointsToSpend.ToString();
        total.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text = (newRank + modificador).ToString();
        skill.Puntos = newRank;
    }
}

private int GetModificador(Skill skill)
{
    int retorno=0;
    if (skill.Clasea)
    {
        retorno += 3;
    }
    else
    {
        retorno += 0;
    }
    retorno += GetModificadorCaracteristica();
    return retorno;
}

private int GetModificadorCaracteristica()
{
    Utils utils = new Utils();
    int retorno = 0;
    int characteristic=0;
    switch (skill.Caracteristica)
    {
        case "Fue":
            characteristic = Almacen.instance.Character.EffectiveStr;
            break;
        case "Des":
            characteristic = Almacen.instance.Character.EffectiveDex;
            break;
        case "Con":
            characteristic = Almacen.instance.Character.EffectiveCon;
            break;
        case "Int":
            characteristic = Almacen.instance.Character.EffectiveInt;
            break;
        case "Sab":
            characteristic = Almacen.instance.Character.EffectiveWis;
            break;
        case "Car":
            characteristic = Almacen.instance.Character.EffectiveCha;
            break;

    }
    retorno = utils.GetCharModifier(characteristic);
    return retorno;
}
}
```

Comment: Your element has negative scales (the red cross indicates that)

Comment: But it doesn't has negative scales...you can see it in the screenshot.

Comment: I can see that it does .. as said on the red cross ... you have set it to be 1700 pixels from the left ... maybe this is simply too much?

Comment: You put me in the correct path...by doing 'listItem.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            listItem.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);' my items appears in the ScrollView. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

it looks like you instantiate the object as a **GameObject**. but this will not be seen in the canvas because it isn't a UI component. you may want to add a sprite or image to the component and instantiate that into the Canvas. it will look something like this:

```
public class SkillPrefab
{
    //put all your variables here!!!

    public Sprite skillSprite;
}


public class YourClassName : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public List<SkillPrefab> skills = new List<SkillPrefab>();

    private void Update()
    {

        Sprite listItem = Instantiate(skills[0].skillSprite);  //the index is the skill you want to spawn in the list.
    }
}
```

this does take into account that you have made your skills into a list of skills that you can acces.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I think I dont fully understand you. My SkillPrefab is a panel with things inside (text, two buttons and three TMP_InputField), I dont need nor want a Sprite in it, due to design. If I am not wrong, the code you provided above will show in the ScrollView only the Sprite, not the component with the things I need. It is not possible to show a set of Panels in a ScrollView?

Comment: could you also put your skillprefab code here. also it i dont think i understand your question,could you clarify because if you want to display properties of the component you  can do that by just accessing them.

Comment: Regarding clarification, I have a List of Skills (skills the character can assign points to). I want a SkillPrefav displayed in the ScrollView for each Skill. The SkillPrefab has Buttons that only affects the corresponding Skill. So, if a Skill is, say, "Jump", if I click the plus Button the value of that skill (and only that skill) should increase in 1 point. Also, there are some other things that can affect the total value of the skill; if a character has a high Dexterity it gets a bonus. That's why the "Modificadores" TMP_InputValue. If you have played D&D it should sound familiar to you.

Comment: Makes absolutely no difference .. it isn't important via which type you instantiate the prefab (either way it will be spawned as GameObject into the scene). It is only important to which parent you spawn the object to. In the Screenshots you can see however that the issue is not related to this

Comment: your problem is that you want to display a gameobject in the UI/Canvas. thats why i was saying you need to get a sprite in the canvas to represent the skill